# Octave-control package installation is not working

Tags: octave

I have sucessfully installed octave and octave-control from ubuntu repo.

but when i try to use it I get following error.

```
enter octave:2> num = [ 1 2]  
num =

1   2

octave:3> den = [ 2 4 6]
 den =

 2    4   6

 octave:4> sys = tf(num,den)
  error: tfpoly: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/control-2.8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/is_real_vector.oct: failed to load: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/control-2.8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/is_real_vector.oct: undefined symbol: _ZNK5ArrayISsE17resize_fill_valueEv
error: called from
tfpoly at line 38 column 7
__vec2tfpoly__ at line 32 column 7
tf at line 223 column 1  3
code here
```

Comment: AFAIK that symbol should be defined in the main liboctave library: all I can suggest is running `ldd` on the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/packages/control-2.8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-api-v50+/is_real_vector.oct` file to see if there are any obvious missing library links, and going from there

Comment: If this error is from packages installed from the Ubuntu repository, please report it as a bug, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs.